# Compiler error: (enumerated class) was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++11, enums, compiler-errors, header-files

I am attempting to compile the following program that utilizes an enumerated class called Noun. It takes input in from a string and enumerates the data using a map.

The following is in the header file that defines the enumerated class:

nouns.h

```
#ifndef NOUNS_H
#define NOUNS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <map>          //std::map
#include <string>       //std::string

#include "classes.h"    // where classes are stored
#include "functions.h"  // standard functions kept here
#include "cmdtree.h"    // where the arguments from these functions are sent


enum class Noun
{
    name,                   
    /* other nouns */
    invalid         
};

std::map < std::string, Noun > knownNouns = 
{
    {   "name",         Noun::name          },
    /* more stuff in the map */
    {   "suspect",      Noun::suspect       }
};

Noun parseNoun(std::string &noun)
{
    auto n = knownNouns.find(noun);
    if ( n == knownNouns.end() ) {
        return Noun::invalid;
    }
    return n->second;
}

void ask (Noun noun);
void look (Noun noun);

#endif  /* NOUNS_H */
```

When I compile, I get a number of errors:

```
In file included from functions.h:16:0,
                 from classes.h:15,
                 from nouns.h:37,
                 from nouns.cpp:1:
verbs.h:44:15: error: 'Noun' was not declared in this scope
 int verbProc (Noun noun, Verb verb);
               ^
verbs.h:44:31: error: expected primary-expression before 'verb'
 int verbProc (Noun noun, Verb verb);
                               ^
verbs.h:44:35: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 int verbProc (Noun noun, Verb verb);
                                   ^
In file included from classes.h:15:0,
                 from nouns.h:37,
                 from nouns.cpp:1:
functions.h:23:32: error: 'Noun' has not been declared
 char validateInput (Verb verb, Noun noun);
                                ^
```

In verbs.h, where it tells me "noun" is not declared in scope, I look at my header file...

verbs.h:

```
#ifndef VERBS_H
#define VERBS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "nouns.h"
#include "classes.h"
#include "functions.h"
/*
 * See the nouns.h header for better documentation on what exactly this
 * is doing.
 */

    enum class Verb
    {
        ask,        // first verb
        /* other verbs */
        invalid     // last verb

    };

    std::map < std::string, Verb > knownVerbs =
    {                                       
        {   "ask",      Verb::ask       },  
        /* other stuff in map */
        {   "examine",  Verb::look      }
    };

    Verb parseVerb(const std::string &verb);
    int verbProc (Noun noun, Verb verb);        // <-- function where Noun is "undeclared."

    #endif  /* VERBS_H */
```

A similar nondelared error is in "functions.h":

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H     
#define FUNCTIONS_H    

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

#include "classes.h"
#include "verbs.h"
#include "nouns.h"
#include "classes.h"
#include "cmdtree.h"

void localPause ();
void readInput (char* &command, const int MAXL, std::string &noun, std::string &verb);
char verifyExit(char exitChoice);
char validateInput (Verb verb, Noun noun); //  <-- error here, "Noun has not been declared"
void initializeSuspect();
void introduction();

#endif  /* FUNCTIONS_H */
```

Can anyone spot something that I cannot?

Comment: I assume you intended the circular includes: `functions.h` includes  both `nouns.h` and `verbs.h` (which includes `nouns.h`), both of which include `functions.h` (for no apparent reason).

Comment: To expand on @WhozCraig's comment: nouns.cpp includes nouns.h. This defines `NOUNS_H` macro, then includes functions.h (note that `Noun` has not yet been encountered). functions.h in turn includes nouns.h - but since NOUNS_H macro is now defined, the entire header is skipped. Working further through functions.h, the compiler sees the declaration `char validateInput (Verb verb, Noun noun);` - but it doesn't know that the name `Noun` means, and says as much.